# old uv map stays after new unwrap

Tags: uv

I'm following the anvil tutorial and have tried unwrapping but after doing the smart unwrap and then making seams, the new unwrap contains the new info as well as the old info on the grid.  How do I make the new info appear by itself\?

Comment: Hello, sir :). You have to reset your UV map first. Select all vertices, and go to *UV->Reset.* Then you can uwrap again.

Comment: Thanks that ws it.